# error al intentar incluir nombre al segungo eje y usando ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Estoy intentado plotear un gráfico en el que haya dos ejes "y". He conseguido casi terminarlo pero aun no sé porqué no puedo poner un nombre al segundo eje y. Adjunto un fragmento de mis datos para que se entienda mejor.[image: ya]

El código que estoy usando es este:

```
    ggplot(BigPlot, aes(x = date)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(y = log10(Parasitemia) + 5, col = Genera, shape=Genera)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = Prevalence / 25), stat = "identity", position=position_dodge(), colour="black", width = 0.5, fill="#999999") +
  ylab("Parasitemia") + xlab("Date") + 
  facet_grid(Year~Genera) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis~ . * 25 , name = "Parasitemia") +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 20, colour = "black"), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90), legend.text = element_text(size=20), 
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 20), axis.title.y = element_text(size = 20), 
        legend.title = element_text(size = 20), strip.text.x = element_text(size = 20))+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank(), strip.text=element_text(size=20)) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),labels=c("February", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October"))
```

La gráfica resultando es esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como veis el segundo eje de la y no tiene  ninguna etiqueta. Si modifico el código y cambio el nombre "Parasitemia" por "Prevalence" en la función scale_y_continuous es decir:

```
scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis~ . * 25 , name = "Prevalence")
```

El gráfico resultante es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo muy bien qué estoy haciendo mal para que R no modifique ni incluya ninguna etiqueta en el segundo eje de la y. Alguna idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece que de este modo

```
scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis~ . * 25 , name = "Prevalence")
```

lo que hace es reescribir el eje y original. Para que tenga un nombre propio el eje secundario debe añadirse el nombre en el eje secundario

```
scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = (name = "Prevalence"))
```

de modo que en tu caso debería ser algo como

```
scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(name = "Prevalence", sec_axis~ . * 25))
```

Espero que te sirva.
Más info [aqui](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/sec_axis.html).

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Carmen! efectivamente asi se cambia el nombre :)

Comment: Estupendo @LuzGarcía-LongoriaBatanete, si la consideras correcta márcala como respuesta para que no quede como pendiente de responder